# How to find identify the best 'maximum search distance' while doing breach depression least cost using Whitebox?

Tags: whitebox-tools, depression-filling

I am trying to preprocess my DEM in GeoTIFF format using breach depression least cost algorithm of Whitebox tool and I need to provide an input value of maximum search distance for cells. How can I know which value to set?

Answer (score 3):

This tool is actually performing a least-cost based region growing operation centred on each of the pit cells contained in the input DEM. This operation grows outwardly from the pit until a target (lower) cell is identified, at which point a breach channel is carved, and which follows the least-cost path connecting the pit and target cell. This search distance parameter will effectively stop the region-growing operation when the current shortest potential least-cost path is longer than this radius parameter. This is probably the most important parameter for this tool, because breaching, when not constrained with a maximum breach length, can result in very long breach channels that dig through significant ridges. Generally, if a depression needs to be resolved with one of these long, deep breach channels, then it's likely the case that the feature should be better handled by filling. However, the vast majority of pit cells in any DEM can be resolved by breach channels that are less than 10 cells in length. A better name for this parameter would probably be maximum breach channel length--I'll have to change it when I get a chance.

So, how should you set this parameter? I would suggest that there are relatively few consequences of using a relatively larger value, since most pits will be resolved with very short breach paths. However, since you don't want to have very long an deep breach trenches, even if there are only a few, then one approach would be to think about the maximum road embankment width, in grid cells. Since in many applications, it is the desire to breach through these embankment features that motivates the use of this algorithm, than I would certainly suggest using this width (or perhaps a twice the width) as your search distance parameter.